# How do I run iOS apps on macOS with Permissive Security enabled?

Tags: macos, ios, security, permission, rosetta

I use a legacy driver called HoRNDIS, which allows me to tether my Android phone's mobile connection over USB. However, because it doesn't use DriverKit, I have to set the Startup Security of macOS to 'Permissive'.

However, I want to run an iOS application, but when I run the app, I get an error: `To open this app, you’ll need to start up your Mac from macOS Recovery and change the Security Policy to Full Security or Reduced Security.` Is there a way I can run the app and have Permissive Security at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a path where you can compile and sign the kext yourself.  This allows you to use Reduced Security instead of Permissive.  Instructions are [here](https://github.com/jwise/HoRNDIS/issues/146) for arm, but it should work the same for intel macs too.  Of course use this instead of "disabled"  `csrutil enable --without kext`

Here are the instructions in case that url goes stale:

```
I'm glad to report that the latest version of HoRNDIS (9.2) works perfectly on Apple Silicon machines with no code changes required!

Basically, just compiling an additional arm64e (not arm64) binary slice to the HoRNDIS kext works! @jwise

Tested on macOS 12.0.1 21A559, "Monterey".

(I do realise that this isn't really an issue per se, but I just felt really bad for all the users complaining about broken functionality here…)

(Plus, speaking from my own personal experience as a fellow developer, I do find it quite helpful when someone else already tested compatibility for me ;P)

If you're a general user coming who just wants to use HoRNDIS on Apple Silicon right this instant…

Ever since macOS / OS X 10.10 Yosemite, Apple has required kernel extensions (kexts) to be signed by developers who are subscribed to the Apple Developer Program, who also have to apply for a special kext signing privilege.

You're… probably not one of those people. ;P

Luckily, there is a way for you to sign your own kexts using an Xcode feature called ad-hoc signing! But it does require changing some settings first.

Switching to "Reduced Security" mode

If you've already placed your Mac in "Reduced Security" mode before, simply skip this section.

Shut down your Apple Silicon Mac.
Press and hold down the power button until the text under the Apple logo says "Loading startup options…", then let go.
Select "Options".
You are now in recoveryOS — enter your password if it asks.
Go to Utilities → Startup Security Utility.
Select "Reduced Security" and enable Allow user management of kernel extensions from identified developers".
Shut down your Apple Silicon Mac.
Disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection)

IMPORTANT: Disabling SIP in any capacity, even partially, will also disable Apple Pay, as well as any iOS-on-macOS apps you may have downloaded from the App Store. This is a strange (and annoying) decision that Apple has decided to make specifically on Apple Silicon, as Apple Pay actually works fine even when SIP is disabled on x86_64 (Intel) Macs.

Follow steps 2〜4 from above.
Go to Utilities → Terminal.
Type in the following to fully disable SIP: csrutil disable
Note: It is possible to only partially disable the part of SIP that enforces kext signature verification (csrutil enable --without kext), but according to Apple, this is apparently an "unsupported configuration". Use it if you wish (as many do already), but please make sure to read and fully understand the warning that csrutil gives if you try.
Reboot your Apple Silicon Mac.
Compiling HoRNDIS for Apple Silicon (arm64e)

Download and install Xcode.
Run the following in a Terminal session. When it asks for your password, it is normal for no characters to show when when you type!
git clone --recursive https://github.com/jwise/HoRNDIS.git
cd Development/HoRNDIS/
xcodebuild -sdk macosx -configuration Release
sudo cp -rv build/Release/HoRNDIS.kext /Library/Extensions/
Go to System Preferences → Security & Privacy and approve the HoRNDIS kernel extension.
Reboot, connect an Android device in USB tethering mode, and enjoy using HoRNDIS again!
```